# What does this mean "Where does optimism bias manifest in our lives?"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I looked up **manifest** but I am still confused on what "Where does optimism bias manifest in our lives?" is asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'[Manifest](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manifest)', in this context, means 'appear' - the sentence is asking where the optimism bias shows up or makes itself apparent in people's lives. Meaning 1.2 from the OED.